# Google Smart Home "Channel" Trait Limitation

Tags: google-smart-home

Google smart home "Channel" trait recommends to keep the channel list below 30 to avoid latency.
[Channel trait Documentation link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/channel)

Is there an upper limit on the channel number list besides the above recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an upper limit on the channel number list besides the above recommendation?

Not really. The only public recommendation is the same as [Smart Home Channel Trait Schema](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/channel) mentions. So, please follow the recommendation of keeping the channel list to 30 channels or less as an upper limit.